# Why a small CSS dot does not have the same proportions in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm working on a website that has a 3-dot menu button in the top. Each of these dots is 4 pixels wide and height, has border-radius: 100% and margin set to 2 pixels.

```css
.dot {
    background: black;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
```

In Chrome 73, it is neither rounded, nor its proportions are 1:1 as you can see on the following picture. It works perfectly, however, on Safari and Firefox.

https://ibin.co/4gvT3AAmOLRr.png

https://ibin.co/4gvTRW3jy4jD.png

Anyone has an idea how to fix it? If I make it bigger or increase the margin, it displays it correctly, but I would like to keep these sizes. Thanks!

-- UPDATE --

This is the minimal code that reproduces the error for me.

```
<style>
  .menu-toggle{
    display: flex;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent
  }
  .menu-toggle .dot{
    background: black;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border:0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px
  }
</style>

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
  <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span></button>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Also, if it helps, I am using MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2 GB, Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB and the external screen is LG 27UD88-W. The error is on both screens.

**-- UPDATE 2 --**

It does the same problem even if I disable the border-radius, the dots aren't the same width: https://ibin.co/4gvn4EJHniRz.png

Also, I found out, that if I go to inspect mode and I toggle the device, it works perfectly.

Comment: im getting a 500 error from your image links

Comment: i have checked it on chrome and it is showing circle. please zoom it and see

Comment: Your code doesn't permit to reproduce what you have in your images. Please include an [MCVE].

Comment: @Kaiido, I updated the question with the Minimal example

Comment: Trying to make it a Live Snippet doesn't reproduces the Issue for me (Chrome 74 on macOs) https://jsfiddle.net/8nsu7Lve/

Comment: @Kaiido it's really interesting, when I open the fiddle, it works perfectly, but once I throw it into html and open directly in the browser, it gets all crazy

Comment: are you adding the `doctype` at the top?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes I am

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` should be 50% for a circular shape.
Also you need to make sure the contents of the circle takes up no space.

As soon as the circle has visible contents, it will turn into a tube (as the width expands).

```css
.dot {
    background: black;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
}

.wrong {
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot wrong"></div>
```

I wasn't actually able to reproduce your non-circle, but this may be the browser compensating for your mistake.

Comment: `the browser compensating for your mistake` (allowing random values over 50%). The actual value should be 50%. https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/559fe347e39efe4cf40005a9

Comment: I'll let you use `border-radius: 5000px`

Comment: Actually I was wrong, If all the corners don't have >= 50% then there is a difference: https://jsfiddle.net/3d5vruo1/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you gotta do is to change your `border-radius` to `50%`. If you still fail to achieve the desired pure circle, try masking it with a single pixel like so:

`-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);`

Comment: It's not even the border-radius. It has different widths when I disable the radius - see my 2nd update

Comment: Then it has certainly gotta do with the surrounding elements because when I used the markup & styles provided by you, my dots get rendered of the same dimensions - https://codepen.io/nirmalhz/pen/gJwgJx

Comment: In codepen or jsfiddle or in any other window (I mentioned also the device view in Chrome's inspect) it renders as it should. It's just the plain html that makes it weird. Even if I just copy the codepen you provided and put it there

Comment: Do you mind sharing a link to your staging, if you have uploaded it somewhere? I might be able to help you out once I debug it

Answer (score 0):

I recently came up to the same issue.
People up-top are right. Border-radius should be 50% to make a circle.

In my case `background-clip: padding-box;` did the trick.

The difference may not be visible in code snippet here but it is visible in my project, especially when zooming in a bit on my browser. (Chrome in my case). Don't know what are the reasons for this minor issue.

Here's the relative [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) that helped me.

And a code snippet that utilizes: `background-clip: padding-box;`

```css
.dot {
    background: black;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
}

.wrong {
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.perfect {
    /* Prevent background color leak outs,
    helps to create a perfect dot and not a square-ish dot */
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip:    padding;
    background-clip:         padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot wrong"></div>
<div class="dot perfect"></div>
```